# RubyonRails Not able to save has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two models `industry_matcher` and `staffroom`

Model IndustryMatcher

```
class IndustryMatcher < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :industries, class_name: 'Staffroom', conditions: ["staffroom_type = 'Industry'"]
```

Model Staffroom

```
class Staffroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industry_matchers
```

Now I have created an ActiveAdmin resource, which basically is a form that takes in the name and industries that user can select from the `select2` field.

```
ActiveAdmin.register IndustryMatcher do
  config.sort_order = 'name_asc'
  menu :parent => 'Job Networks', :label => 'Industry Matcher'


  form do |f|
    f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
    f.inputs 'Industry' do
      f.input :name
      f.input :industries, :include_blank => false, :as => :select, :multiple => true, :input_html => {class: "chzn-select"}, collection: Staffroom.industry
      end
      f.actions
  end

end
```

I am able to save the data for model IndustryMatcher but the relationship does not get saved at all.

This is the model class that links the two

```
class IndustryMatcherStaffroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :industry_id, :staffroom_id

  belongs_to :industry_matcher
  belongs_to :staffroom
end
```

I will really appreciate if someone can tell me what i am missing here and why the relationship does not get saved.

After saving the record when I try to edit it, i see the following error

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /admin/industry_matchers/11/edit
>   PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column staffrooms.industry_matcher_id
>   does not exist LINE 1: ...affrooms"  WHERE "staffrooms"."deleted" =
>   'f' AND "staffroom...
>                                                                ^ : SELECT "staffrooms".id FROM "staffrooms"  WHERE "staffrooms"."deleted"
>   = 'f' AND "staffrooms"."industry_matcher_id" = 11 AND (staffroom_type = 'Industry')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations are incomplete, you must tell your models to use the join table by using  `has_many through:`, like this:

```
class IndustryMatcher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industry_matcher_staffrooms 
  has_many :industries, through: :industry_matcher_staffrooms, class_name: 'Staffroom', conditions: ["staffroom_type = 'Industry'"]

class Staffroom < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :industry_matcher_staffrooms
  has_many :industry_matchers, through: :industry_matcher_staffrooms
```

Since you didn't specified your models to use the join table (i.e. `IndustryMatcherStaffroom` model), rails treated your associations as *one-to-many* connection, and looked for the related id (i.e. `industry_matcher_id`) in the `staffrooms` table, thus the error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column staffrooms.industry_matcher_id does not exist
```

You can read more about associations in the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Comment: Thanks but this gives an error NameError - undefined local variable or method `industry_matcher_staffrooms', i even tried adding   has_many :industry_matcher_staffrooms on top of it

Comment: @Saadia Sorry, i missed the `:` in `:industry_matcher_staffrooms`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @Saadia No need for that extra `has_many :industry_matcher_staffrooms`, just use `through: :industry_matcher_staffrooms`.

Comment: Thanks, I am now running into undefined method `klass' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @Saadia My bad, you **do** need the `has_many :industry_matcher_staffrooms` as well; check updated answer please.

Comment: Thanks alot for all the help